# Memory Core Dump C++

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

Now, I have called python to C++. Using ctype to connect between both of them. And I have a problem about core dump when in running time.

I have a library which is called "libfst.so"
This is my code.
NGramFST.h

```
#include <iostream>
class NGramFST{
private:
    static NGramFST* m_Instace;

public:
    NGramFST(){
    }

    static NGramFST* getInstance() {
        if (m_Instace == NULL){
            m_Instace = new NGramFST();
        }
        return m_Instace;
    }

    double getProbabilityOfWord(std::string word, std::string context) {
        std::cout << "reloading..." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

};
```

NGramFST.cpp

```
#include "NGramFST.h"
NGramFST* NGramFST::m_Instace = NULL;

extern "C" {
    double FST_getProbability(std::string word, std::string context){
        return NGramFST::getInstance()->getProbabilityOfWord(word, context);
    }
}
```

And this is my python code.

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfst.so')

#-------------------------main code------------------------
class FST(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Initializing'

    def getProbabilityOfWord(self, word, context):
        lib.FST_getProbability(word, context)

fst = FST()
print fst.getProbabilityOfWord(c_wchar_p('jack london'), c_wchar_p('my name is'))
```

This is error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I reviewed again but I can not detect where is my problem.

Comment: ctypes is not called c++types for a reason. It cannot magically convert a Python string to a C++ string. It knows nothing about C++ types. Either use a C compatible interface for your library, or create a module with a modern Python binding library such as pybind11.

Comment: I think it have a problem when I create instance, not about type of param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctypes` does not understand C++ types (it's not called `c++types`). It cannot handle `std::string`. It wouldn't know that your function expects `std::string` arguments anyway.

In order to work with `ctypes`, your library needs a C-compatible interface. `extern "C"` is necessary but not sufficient. The functions need to be actually callable from C.

Better yet, use a modern C++/Python binding library such as [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: After that, I change type of param and it work. Thank friend.

Answer (score 0):

It work when I change python code below

```
string1 = "my string 1"
string2 = "my string 2"

# create byte objects from the strings
b_string1 = string1.encode('utf-8')
b_string2 = string2.encode('utf-8')

print fst.getProbabilityOfWord(b_string1, b_string2)
```

and c++ code change type of param bellow

```
FST_getProbability(const char* word, const char* context)
```